# Multiple @media tags not working

Tags: css, responsive-design

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
       html { background-color: green; }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 766px) {
       html { background-color: green; }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
       html { background-color: green; }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
       html { background-color: green; }
    }

    html { 
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

I'm using opera, 1920x1080 screen. The first @media tag works, the background changes to green when opera is at 100% zoom.

Changing zoom to 90% makes the background blue already...and it stays blue the whole time even at 10% zoom. Why is that so?

The first @media tag seems to be working, the others don't. And even so the first tag doesn't work properly (90% * 1080px > 767px; so the color should be green while at 90% zoom but it's not).

Comment: why don't you try resizing the window to see the different colours instead. try this http://jsfiddle.net/99g8N/ and resize window

Answer (score 1):

Move your single html definition to the top, you can also reduce the media queries to just use max

```
    html {  
        background-color: blue;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
       html { background-color: green; }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
       html { background-color: red; }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
       html { background-color: black; }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
       html { background-color: white; }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5tLf/